# glob in solaris csh

Tags: solaris, glob, csh

I want to list all the directories that start with . in the current directory. I don't want the previous directory (..) to be listed so I had the <del>regular expression</del> something like this. I am using csh

```
ls .[^.]*
```

It works fine on UNIX variant platforms but in solaris, I am still using the csh but it lists me only .. directory. How can I specify the <del>regular expression</del> with the exact functionality in Solaris. It works in bash but I have to use csh only as it is guaranteed to be available on each SOLARIS box in our org.

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt HTH. I can't imagine why a bourne shell wouldn't be on all of your solaris boxes.

Comment: Confirmed on Solaris 9.  I'd suggest using `tcsh` instead, but if you can't count on bash I suppose you can't count on tcsh.  Incidentally, that's a file matching pattern, not a regular expression.  I think `grep`, as **mu is too short** suggested, is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `/bin/sh`, but with a slightly different syntax; it uses `!` rather than `^` to negate the set of characters:

```
ls .[!.]*
```

Note that this is a file matching pattern (a *glob*), not a regular expression.

But given the variations you're seeing in the glob syntax supported by various shells, you might be better off using `grep` with actual regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`csh`? Wow, I didn't know they still made that :) Your `ls .[^.]*` works on OSX's `csh` so I don't know what's going on with the Solaris `csh`. A crufty backup would be something like this:

```
ls `ls -a | grep '^\.[^.].*'`
```

The `-a` for `ls` tells it to include all the dot-files in the list and then a bit of `grep` for dealing with the dots. That matches what `ls .[^.]*` does in OSX's `csh`, hopefully it will work with Solaris's as well.

Answer (score 0):

Character classes in globs in csh don't support negation...

From the man page in Solaris:

```
 [...] Match any single character in the enclosed list(s)  or
       range(s).  A  list is a string of characters.  A range
       is  two  characters  separated  by  a  dash  (-),  and
       includes  all  the  characters in between in the ASCII
       collating sequence (see ascii(5)).
```

So... you could create a character class that includes a range from \040 (space) to '-' (the character before '.', then from '/' to '~' (the remaining printable ascii characters).

```
ls -a .[\ --/-~]*
```

This seems to work for me, but I haven't checked the output with a fine-toothed comb.